# Php Warning error

Tags: software-installation, php, libraries

When I execute the command `php -v` on Ubuntu, I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_get_client_info), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Are you sure about the "pdo_mysql.so.so" ??  Looks like one extension too many.

Comment: yes, this is the warning. I just copy it

Comment: Did you make any changes to php.ini?